# Is there a limit to updating multiple columns in a single MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm using Perl and DBI package to do the MySQL connections and commands. I found threads about the power of one query to do multiple updates on columns.

Is there a limitation? Can I build a single query that would update 50,000 rows with unique data?

Comment: You need to explain what sort of query you are thinking of. I imagine it's something more than `UPDATE table SET column = column + 1`? Please link to the threads that you are talking about.

Comment: There is a limitation: `max_allowed_packet`. If you try to execute a query larger than that setting, you'll get a [Packet Too Large](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html) error.

Comment: It sounds like you want to loop and run the same query multiple times with different data.  If that is the case you certainly can.

Comment: If you're trying to do a mass import of data on the order of 50,000 rows, [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) is likely to be the fastest route.

Comment: ah ok, i was looking for this max_allowed_packet

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot you should make that an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limitation: you cannot execute a query larger than [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) bytes or you will get a [packet too large](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html) error. In MySQL 5.5, the default value is 1MB for the server and 1GB for the client library (but only 16MB for the `mysql` command line utility).

You should look at [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) as a possible alternative; for 50,000 rows, it is likely to be faster than compound inserts, and you wouldn't have to worry about exceeding `max_allowed_packet`.